# How cordova/ionic works?

Tags: android, cordova

I have an application writing in Javascript to run on Android OS. At first, I was run the app on android webview, but, cordovas do it and do it good. So, how cordovas do it? An application in JS run better on cordova framework or android native?

Some important points: I will play video, images and canvas in app
                                      My application is a videoplayer

Answer (score 2):

Ionic framework is on the base of Cordova and angular js. It builds your app for both IOS and android OS. The application runs on the native browser of your phone, and you can achieve all native functionalities using cordova. So if you are a javascript developer it wont take any effort to learn and create a mobile app using IONIC. Basically if you are going for a hybrid mobile application then IONIC framework is one of the best.Ionic will provide you a lot of custom directives  for quick and easy development. Also you can take a look at ReactNative.

Comment: or NativeScript for that matter.